# Way to memorize shape - number combinations in short time

Tags: logical-deduction

A visual memory test application gives some time to memorize **images - numbers** combinations, after that it shows a random shape and asks what the number is. What is to trick for such an application if your memory is not very good. [Run The Visual Test](http://www3.telus.net/eugene_k/Space/Mem-ESA-ASPP-2008.swf)

[image]

Comment: Note that as this question is subjective, answers should adhere to our [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) guidelines. Please refrain from speculating on what might work in answers - keep them based on experience and/or backed up by references. Thank you!

Comment: Best way to cheat here - just make a photo)

Comment: I find creating a narrative helps.  For the above set I would try to remember "39 red birds flew over the KHallisi when she was 15 but 96 healers could not save JeoFfry from being stabbed 35 times."  This is most effective if you mix quantities of actions, with quantities of items, ages, temperatures, times, etc as this adds extra depth and it is less likely to get muddled in a mass of objects and adds depth to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering a map of numbers to pictures requires your memory to map the numbers to shapes with any explanation you can think of i.e. in the above case say,

(+) -> 96.... (When I see 96, rotation leads to 96,so is for +).

JF-> 35.... (J looks like half 3 with lower part missing; F is 5 with lower part missing ).

KH ->15.... (H then I(1)...)

RED arrow -> 39 ( The arow's end looks like a 3 and RED(3)*3(arrow'send)=9) :P

It sounds ambiguous, but the logic of mapping is "to each his own".

Some simple ways:

a) Use math (a=1,b=2....z=26) to map shapes to numbers.

b) Use the picture's design ,make it synonymous to a number.

NOTE: It need not be a logical mapping, any random thoughts.

Comment: This is not tricks, this is exactly what you need to do in such cases - this is how memory works.

Comment: Agreed.. Missed the want for tricks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think of, there are only two ways, you remember or you find someone/some tool who/which can remember.

That someone who can remember can be a screenshot (as suggested in comments by klm123) or another person who can sit beside you and tell you the answer.

Another solution is to find patterns if any and apply the same, but this is not an universal solution.  As indicated by Emrakul these are subjective answers that I have used personally for other such similar situations (not tests)